# Wrap a returned Geb Navigator with an interface

Tags: functional-testing, geb

I have a span element in a page that emulates a checkbox. Whether this "checkbox" is "checked" is set by giving the element some class.

In my Page, I've got a method that returns this element using a $() selector (I.E. a Navigator instance):

```
class MyPage extends page {

    def getCheckbox(String searchStr) {
        $("div.parent").find(".class-a", text: searchStr)
    }
    def myFunc() {
        def cb = getCheckbox("foo")
        if (cb.has(".class-B") {
            // checkbox is ticked. do something...
        }
    }
}
```

I'm looking for a way to decorate the object returned from `getCheckbox()`, so that clients wishing to check the status of the checkbox can do `cb.isChecked()` instead of the more-obscure `has(".class-B")` (I.E to attain a similar interface to the builtin `checkbox` form control module)

Any suggestions?
Thanks!

Comment: You could always just make a method called `isChecked(Navigator cb)` that wraps `.has(".class-B")` and call that, there is also a way to override the Navigator Interface, in which case you can create your own Navigator methods. That seems like a complicated solution for such a simple thing, but if that's what you are after I can answer the question showing you how you can override the Navigator interface.  That's the only way I know for you to call something like cb.isChecked() assuming cb is a Navigator.

Answer (score 1):

Your checkbox emulating span element is a prime candidate for becoming a Geb [module](http://gebish.org/manual/current/#modules) - simply define a module class with the methods that you want to exists on your wrapper and then pass it to the Navigator's `module()` method for the navigator representing your span element.

Answer (score 0):

how about this:

```
class CheckBoxNavigator extends NonEmptyNavigator {
    def isChecked(){
        return this.has(".class-B")
    }
}
```

Then you just need to define your checkBox element as a "CheckBoxNavigator" and then you can use `isChecked()`